# How to override Ant Design select arrow over the project?

Tags: antd

There is Ant Design suffixIcon property which allows to customize select arrow icon in a single select. Is there any way to override suffixIcon for all selects over the whole project?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to make changes in the whole project is via the [Config Provider](https://ant.design/components/config-provider/), but I can't find a specific config to change the `suffixIcon`